# Plesk 9.5 IIS 7 Fast CGI timeout error 500

Tags: php, iis, cgi, fastcgi, plesk

I'm running the following setup:
- Windows 2008 web edition
- IIS 7
- Plesk 9.5
- FastCGI

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION

When running a script that takes longer than 30 seconds, I get the 500 internal server error message and not the "normal" response ("max execution time of 30 seconds is reached"). Also, this message always appears after about 40 secondes. Also, after putting set_time_limit(3600); into the code this same results happen.

ACTUAL RESULT

Both with and without the set_time_limit code:

After about 40 seconds a 500 internal server error appears

EXPECTED RESULT

Without set_time_limit:

After 30 seconds a message will appear saying the 30 seconds max execution limit is reached.

With set_time_limit:

The full script runs with a max of the number of seconds set in the set_time_limit

ADITIONAL NOTE

The problem is solved when running CGI in stead of FastCGI.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could found some links that could help you. The problem is the activityTimeout of your cgi module.

- [Increase fastCgi / PHP activityTimeout in IIS7](http://www.bokko.nl/increase-fastcgi-php-activitytimeout-in-iis7/)
- [FastCGI timeout value change](http://tech.mikeal.com/blog1.php/fastcgi-timeout-value-change)

For my, works in summary this.

Open the dos console "cmd" and go to 
`c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\`
then, execute this command, changing the path of your `php-cgi`.
`appcmd set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi "-[fullPath='C:\php\php-cgi.exe'].activityTimeout:3600"`

I hope this help you!